# Compact set and function with no extremum

Tags: derivatives

I have to find compact set $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with non-empty interior and differentiable function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which don't have local extremum in every interior point of $D$. Any hints?

Comment: What have you tried? Think very simply. Consider the unit square. Can you think of a very simple function with no extremum on the interior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$D=\left[0,{\pi\over2}\right]^2, f(x,y)=\sin x$$ makes sure the extremums are on the boundary and $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Please try not to give complete solutions to homework problems.  Provide a hint instead.

Comment: @guest Should I delete it?

Comment: No, I do not think you should delete the answer since you took the trouble to post it (and nobody should or can force you to delete any answers).  It is correct and will help the OP.  I made that remark so that in the future you try to follow the 'hint' route to questions that have homework flavor.  +1 for simple, correct solution and to emphasize there is no need for deletion.